# How to check whether I can iterate trhough numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I can iterate over y, but not over x.

```
x = np.array(1)
y = np.array([1])
    
print(f'x --- shape: {np.shape(x)}, iter: {hasattr(x, "__iter__")}')
print(f'y --- shape:  {np.shape(y)}, iter: {hasattr(y, "__iter__")}, len: {len(y)}')
```

Output:

```
x --- shape: (), iter: True
y --- shape:  (1,), iter: True, len: 1
```

`len(x)` doesn't work --> type error, since it's an unsized object.
Iterating through x --> type error, since it's an 0-d array.

I'd like to check before if it's iterable and if not, make it a (1,) array. How though? x does have the `__iter__` atribute... so this won't help either.

Comment: Why are you initializing a numpy array with a non-array-like object?

Comment: @Malcolm I could probably avoid this. I was just trying to avoid any runtime errors.

Comment: One typical python pattern for handling situations like this where certain input might throw an exception, is to not add checks to avoid the exception, but to just use a try/catch to deal with it.

Comment: If you really want to, though, you have the solution in your own output `len(np.shape(x)) > 0` would be False for x and True for y.

Comment: `np.atleast_1d` may be useful.  Though all it does it check id `ndim==0`, and do a `reshape` if necessary (read its code).  Or `np.array(1, ndmin=1)`

Comment: Also relevant: [`np.iterable`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.iterable.html)

Comment: Do you really need to iterate?

Comment: Why not check like ```x.ndim > 0```?